# How to inject Spring bean into JSF converter

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I need to inject Spring beans into a JSF (Primefaces) converter. I tried to inject beans by using EL resolver. However, the beans are `null` inside the converters.

My JSF converter:

```
public class DepartmentConverter implements Converter  {
    private DepartmentService departmentService;
    //getter setter for this property

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        //codes
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        //Codes
    }
}
```

`faces-config.xml`:

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>DepartmentConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.studinfo.jsf.converter.DepartmentConverter</converter-class>
    <property>
        <property-name>departmentService</property-name>
        <property-class>com.studinfo.services.DepartmentService</property-class>
        <default-value>#{DepartmentService}</default-value>
    </property>
</converter>
```

EL resolver:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

When I debug my code, the `departmentService` property is `null`. I can access the Spring beans inside a managed JSF bean the same way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Until JSF 2.3, converters are no injection targets. Make the converter a JSF or Spring managed bean instead. The below example makes it a JSF managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DepartmentConverter implements Converter  {
    // ...
}
```

And use it as `#{departmentConverter}` instead of `DepartmentConverter`.

E.g.

```
<h:inputSome ... converter="#{departmentConverter}" />
```

or

```
<h:someComponent>
    <f:converter binding="#{departmentConverter}" />
</h:someComponent>
```

Don't forget to remove the `<converter>` from `faces-config.xml` (which was at its own already unnecessary if you used the `@FacesConverter` annotation, but that aside).